# ¿Método For "especial" en Python?

Tags: python

Quisiera saber si alguien sabe la estructura especial del For en Python (y si es posible su nombre, recuerdo que tiene uno)... era algo parecido a esto:

```
x*2 for x in [1,2,3]:
  print(x)
```

Creo que era más o menos así, y debería devolver los valores del arreglo ingresados en la función de la izquierda:

```
2
4
6
```

Les agradecería, se que es sencillo pero estoy perdido con la sintaxis y el nombre de esto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo encontré, se llama ***Lista por comprensión***.
Tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
def funcion(arreglo):
    return [x for x in arreglo if x>1]
```

- x es la operación a realizar sobre el elemento
- Con un condicional podemos dar mas restricciones a que elementos del arreglo queremos aplicarle la operación.